# HttpURLConnection not establishing

Tags: android

Hello friends, I am new for web services making just simple application which establish connection.
Below is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView text;
String ip = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    try{            
        URL url=new URL(ip);
        executeReq(url);

        text.setText("Connection Available");               
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        text.setText("Connectionn Failed");
    }
}

private void executeReq(URL url) throws IOException{

    HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    con.setReadTimeout(10000);
    con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");               

    con.connect();                  
}
```

}

I have also declared permission in manifest file but i can not finding fault.
 please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you except us to help you without the stack trace ? :)

Comment: Stackoverflow needs Stacktrace for better help and answers.

Comment: you should use asynctak for network related operation or create a new thread. should not make network related operation on the ui thread

Comment: @Raghunandan: shall we get into a chat....

Comment: @Vinothbabu which chat room? and what topic?

Comment: @Raghunandan: which one.

Comment: you might be getting `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` if you are working on sdk 11 or above.

Comment: @Vinothbabu which chat room to enter and what's the topic?

Comment: @Raghunandan: Just casual discussion, nothing too technical... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23658/java-sucks

Answer (score 0):

This code will trigger a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Try using `AsyncTask` to achieve this.

For more info: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

This might works an Android firmware above the 3.0 but now It's not handled anymore.

AsyncTask is better anyway, its offering you to avoid the freeze of your application while you are trying to connect / send object, etc.